# ¿Como comparar dos valores diferentes en java? Ejemplo [+ y -]

Tags: java, array, poo

Lo que quiero hacer es compara a mi operador actual `+` o cualquier otro operador aritmético con cualquiera de los operadores que tengo con anterioridad que también son aritméticos,

Tengo `4+-`, esto de aqui es erroneo entonces quiero hacer que se detecte si hay un signo antes ya escrito no me realice nada y mande error.

```
remover=txtResultado.getText().toString();
String substringCadena=remover.substring(0,remover.substring.lenght-1);
        if (elemento.toString().equals(substringCadena)) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No puede haber dos operadores consecutivos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            contaOp=0;
        return;
        }
```

El problema de eso es que si tengo `++` me va a marcar el error, pero si tengo `+-` no me marca el error y se debe a que no son iguales. entonces como hago que esto pueda ser factible.

Comment: en substringCadena, pretendes meter ++, o -- por ejemplo? no te entiendo, qué hace, lee lo que escribes a tiempo real? (parece que falta código!!)

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz en SubstringCadena se quiere mete un solo signo "+" y ese debe compararse con cualquiera de los 4 simbolos "+,-,*,/" que pudieran estar con anterioridad

Answer (score 1):

La opción que yo usaría sería recorrer toda la cadena con un for y habilitar una bandera cuando encuentre un operador entonces si encuentra otro operador mientras la bandera esta activa mandas el error algo así:

```
String txt=txt.getText().toString();

String op[]={"+","-","*","/"};

int i,j;

boolean ban=false;

for(i=0;i<txt.length();i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<op.length;j++)
    {
          if((txt.chatAt(i)+"").equals(op[j]))//Compara el caracter actual de la cadena con un operador y si es igual entra
          {
                if(ban)//Si la bandera es verdadera es porque ya se habia encontrado un operador antes por lo tanto se despliega el error
                {
                     System.out.println("error");
                     ban=false;
                }
                else
                     ban=true;//Si no se había encontrado un operador antes la bandera se pone en estado verdadero
                break;
          }
    }
    if(j==op.lenght)//En caso de que no encuentre un operador significa que es un numero por lo que la bandera se pone en falso
         ban=false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Voy a tratar de explicarte, ya que parece que hay algo que no queda claro. Tu código tiene bastantes problemas de primeras:

```
//Aquí parece que asignas a remover el contenido en texto de un objeto llamado "txtResultado"

remover=txtResultado.getText().toString();

//El problema es que a continuación dices que "substringCadena" es resultado de hacer el substring desde Cero a la longitud de `remover.substring`. Esto no tiene sentido, ya que "remover.substring" como tal, no existe. Por otra parte, llamas a la longitud total -1 por lo que si fuera remover.substring(0,remover.lenght-1) únicamente te cogería todos los valores y nada más (no haría ningún substring).

String substringCadena=remover.substring(0,remover.substring.lenght-1);

//Aquí comparas la variable "elemento" que tampoco existía antes, por lo que nosotros en stackoverflow sabemos ni qué tiene, por lo que resulta imposible saber lo que quieres.
        if (elemento.toString().equals(substringCadena)) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No puede haber dos operadores consecutivos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            contaOp=0;
        return;
        }
```

Si nos cuentas un poco más y añades las declaraciones que faltan, o explicas qué es cada variable, quizá podamos ayudarte más.